# See-option gets removed when using nonumberlist with glossaries

Tags: glossaries

as seen in the following MWE, the `see`-option of a `newglossaryentry`-acronym which refers to a normal glossary entry gets removed when printed.
Removing the `nonumberlist`-option of the `glossaries`-package gets me the desired result.
Is there any way to resolve this issue?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[acronym,nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

%%% The glossary entry the acronym links to   
\newglossaryentry{apig}{name={API},
    description={An Application Programming Interface (API) is a particular set
of rules and specifications that a software program can follow to access and
make use of the services and resources provided by another particular software
program that implements that API}}

%%% define the acronym and use the see= option
\newglossaryentry{api}{type=\acronymtype, name={API}, description={Application
Programming Interface}, first={Application
Programming Interface (API)\glsadd{apig}}, see=[Glossary:]{apig}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{First Frame}
    First use \gls{api}

    subsequent \gls{api}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \printglossary[type=main]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Apparently stackexchange won't let me put a greeting in front of the question. I tried to edit it accordingly; with no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Glossary Appearance Options](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:pkgopts-printglos):

> **seeautonumberlist**
>       If you suppress the number lists with `nonumberlist`, described above, this will also suppress any cross-referencing information
>   supplied by the `see` key in `\newglossaryentry` or `\glssee`. If you use
>   `seeautonumberlist`, the `see` key will automatically implement
>   `nonumberlist=false` for that entry. (Note this doesn’t affect `\glssee`.)
>   For further details see §8 Cross-Referencing Entries.

So you can just add `seeautonumberlist`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[acronym,nonumberlist,seeautonumberlist]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

%%% The glossary entry the acronym links to   
\newglossaryentry{apig}{name={API},
    description={An Application Programming Interface (API) is a
particular set
of rules and specifications that a software program can follow to
access and
make use of the services and resources provided by another
particular software
program that implements that API}}

%%% define the acronym and use the see= option
\newglossaryentry{api}{type=\acronymtype, name={API},
description={Application
Programming Interface}, first={Application
Programming Interface (API)\glsadd{apig}}, see=[Glossary:]{apig}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{First Frame}
    First use \gls{api}

    subsequent \gls{api}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \printglossary[type=main]
\end{frame}
```

However, you'll get the locations as well as the cross-reference for that entry:

API Application Programming Interface. 1, Glossary: API

There are two possible alternatives:

1. Add the cross-reference to the description instead:

   ```
   \documentclass{beamer}
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   \usepackage[acronym,nonumberlist]{glossaries}
   \makeglossaries

   %%% The glossary entry the acronym links to   
   \newglossaryentry{apig}{name={API},
       description={An Application Programming Interface (API) is a
   particular set
   of rules and specifications that a software program can follow to
   access and
   make use of the services and resources provided by another
   particular software
   program that implements that API}}

   %%% define the acronym a
   \newglossaryentry{api}{type=\acronymtype, name={API},
   description={Application
   Programming Interface, \glsseeformat[Glossary:]{apig}{}}, first={Application
   Programming Interface (API)\glsadd{apig}}}

   \begin{document}

   \begin{frame}{First Frame}
       First use \gls{api}

       subsequent \gls{api}
   \end{frame}

   \begin{frame}
       \printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
   \end{frame}
   \begin{frame}
       \printglossary[type=main]
   \end{frame}

   \end{document}
   ```
2. Use the extension package [`glossaries-extra`](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra). (This requires fairly up-to-date versions of both `glossaries` and `glossaries-extra`.)

   ```
   \documentclass{beamer}
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   \usepackage[acronym,nonumberlist]{glossaries-extra}
   \makeglossaries

   %%% The glossary entry the acronym links to   
   \newglossaryentry{apig}{name={API},
       description={An Application Programming Interface (API) is a
   particular set
   of rules and specifications that a software program can follow to
   access and
   make use of the services and resources provided by another
   particular software
   program that implements that API}}

   %%% define the acronym and use the see= option

   \setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}

   \newacronym[see={[Glossary:]{apig}}]{api}{API}{Application
   Programming Interface}

   \renewcommand{\glsxtrpostdescacronym}{%
    \ifglshasfield{see}{\glscurrententrylabel}%
    {%
      \glsfieldfetch{\glscurrententrylabel}{see}{\thisxr}%
      , \expandafter\glsseeformat\thisxr{}%
    }% 
    {}%
   }

   \begin{document}

   \begin{frame}{First Frame}
       First use \gls{api}

       subsequent \gls{api}
   \end{frame}

   \begin{frame}
       \printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
   \end{frame}
   \begin{frame}
       \printglossary[type=main]
   \end{frame}
   \end{document}
   ```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. It works with the command `\newacronym` but not with `\newglossaryentry`.  Maybe I've misunderstodd something. And yes, I haven't put it into the question. I changed it after writing this question, because I use the `first=`-option from `\newglossaryentry`.